# Python LinkedIn API problem (OAuth)

Tags: python, oauth, linkedin-api

has anyone used the pylinkedin library ?
After redirection from LinkedIn when I try to get the accessToken LinkedIn returns oauth_problem=permission_unknown
Any clues

Answer (score 0):

I think our fork of the Linkedin-Client-Library is much more complete (yet a bit heavy)

https://github.com/PhilGo20/LinkedIn-Client-Library